# When the font size is changed in the phone, text, buttons go out of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, font-size

I came across a problem and I don't know where to look for information, in case you know how to resolve my problem, please lend me your help.
I tried my app on another phone, it is the same type of phone with the same api. The thing is that one of the phones has the font size bigger and the icons/buttons leave the screen. 
Is there a way to set my app to open in a particular type of font size (ex: Tiny, extra small, etc)?
Thanks in advance!

Later Edit:

---

Here's the code of my xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center"
tools:context="****"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/login_first_dialog"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorMainActivity"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="@string/login_second_dialog"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorMainActivity"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonPhoneNumberID"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button_style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:text="@string/phone_button"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorMainActivity"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonHelpLoginID"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_help_outline_black_24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button_style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:text="@string/complaints_button"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorMainActivity"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextLogInEnterEmailID"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextLogInEnterPasswordID"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LogInButtonID"
        android:background="@drawable/login2_button_style"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#808e85"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/log_in_button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SignUpButtonID"
        android:background="@drawable/login2_button_style"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_person_add_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_button"
        android:textColor="#808e85"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/ProgressBarLogInID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you provide, please the code of your xml layout?

Comment: Yeah, of course, I'll update it right now

Comment: You're setting fix sized width for your views.. even if you don't change the size on the same device you'll have problems on different devices.. try using `wrap_content` or `match_parent`

Comment: Okay, thanks! I will do that :)!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `sp` units to indicate the font size on `Button` `TextView` and so on... Instead, use `dp`.

For example:
You might have this in you layout xml file
`text_size="10sp"` change that to `10dp`

Comment: That's not the problem, even if I changed sp to dp (to be hoest I didn't tink it will change something) when I change the font size on my phone, the writing occupies to much of the screen and the buttons tend to "leave the screen". So, nothing changed

Comment: sp is scaled by the user’s font size preference, so changing sp to dp  should make the text stay the same. Post screenshots, for us to have a more clear understating of what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Please, ***do not*** use "dp" for the attribute **android:textSize** in **TextView**. 
Use instead "sp" for text size e.g. **android:textSize="30sp"**
You can use "dp" for any margin or padding related stuff.
Checkout this link for more explanation: [What is the difference between "px", "dip", "dp" and "sp"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp)

Comment: I didn't use dp for text size the first time I made the layout, I changed them only because Eddie told me to try and see if it works. Originally I used sp for text size

Comment: Okay, by the way, did you tried to the ConstraintLayout? Because it could be negative for the performance of your app to have 4 nested LinearLayouts.